# Python is ignoring my if statements inside the loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm trying make a loop to ask the user for a selection which is a string, convert it into an integer, and calculate the total and keep asking until the user inputs q for quit. Everything goes well except that my if statements are completely ignored by Python. Can anyone help me?

My code so far looks like this:

```
l = 0.89
g = 2.50
p = 0.50
t = 0.75
o = 0.50
Subtotal = 0
Total = 0
q = ""
quanity = 0
choice = ""

choice = input('L - Lettuce \nG - Green Beans \nP - Peppers \nT - Tomatoes \nO - Onions \nS - Seasonal Item \nQ - Quit')

while choice != q:
   Subtotal = 0
   quanity = 0
   quanity = input('How Many?')
   if choice == l:
      choice = 0.89
   elif choice == g:
      choice = 2.50
   elif choice == p:
      choice = 0.50
   elif choice == t:
      choice = 0.75
   elif choice == o:
      choice = 0.50
   Subtotal = choice * quanity
   Total = Total + Subtotal
   print('Your total so far is $' ,Total)
   choice = ""
   choice = input('L - Lettuce \nG - Green Beans \nP - Peppers \nT - Tomatoes \nO - Onions \nS - Seasonal Item \nQ - Quit')
print('All Done')
```

Comment: What do you mean by “completely ignored”? What exactly happens? Have you consulted you [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: Btw., I barely know any python and still can use this program without problems just from reading your code. This strongly suggests that you should read the article I linked above and follow it carefully.

Comment: You should provide few test cases with the actual output and the desired one. Otherwise, it is very difficult to be helpful. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The user gave me `L` and it says it's not equal to `2.5`, what gives? Do you see a problem with that logic?

Answer (score 3):

You're testing a `str` from `input` against the variables that contain `float` values. Of course nothing hits. Make the tests check something like:

```
choice = choice.upper()
if choice == 'L':
    choice = l
elif choice == 'G':
    choice = g
```

etc.

Mind you, a more succinct solution would be to define a mapping from letters to values, so you're not using that many chained comparisons:

```
# Defined up front to avoid reconstructing over and over
choicemap = {'L': l, 'G': g, 'P': p, 'T': t, 'O': o}

# Avoid duplicating input code, infinite loop with break on 'Q' input
while True:
    choice = input('L - Lettuce \nG - Green Beans \nP - Peppers \nT - Tomatoes \nO - Onions \nS - Seasonal Item \nQ - Quit').upper()

    try:
        choice = choicemap[choice]
    except KeyError:
        if choice == 'Q':
            break
        print("{!r} is not a recognized option".format(choice)
        continue

    try:
        quanity = int(input('How Many?'))
    except ValueError:
        print("Non-numeric input provided, try again")
        continue

    Total += choice * quanity
    print('Your total so far is $', Total)

print('All Done')
```

Comment: Might also use a dictionary `{"L": 0.89, ...}`

Comment: @tobias_k: I was writing that alternate solution when you posted. :-)

Comment: Also, the while loop is checking whether the input is `q`, and they delcare `q = ""`, so it's not checking for `"q"`, it's checking for `""` Maybe they should do a little more research on how variables work

Answer (score 0):

```
l = 0.89
g = 2.50
p = 0.50
t = 0.75
o = 0.50
Subtotal = 0
Total = 0
q = ""
quanity = 0
choice = ""

choice = input('L - Lettuce \nG - Green Beans \nP - Peppers \nT - Tomatoes \nO - Onions \nS - Seasonal Item \nQ - Quit')

while choice != 'q':
   Subtotal = 0
   quanity = 0
   quanity = float(input('How Many?'))
   if choice == 'l':
      choice = 0.89
   elif choice == 'g':
      choice = 2.50
   elif choice == 'p':
      choice = 0.50
   elif choice == 't':
      choice = 0.75
   elif choice == 'o':
      choice = 0.50
   Subtotal = choice * quanity
   Total = Total + Subtotal
   print('Your total so far is $' ,Total)
   choice = ""
   choice = input('L - Lettuce \nG - Green Beans \nP - Peppers \nT - Tomatoes \nO - Onions \nS - Seasonal Item \nQ - Quit')
print('All Done')
```

You need to add `float` before input, because `input()` returns a string in python 3.x.
Also you're comparing strings, `if choice == 'string':`.

Comment: I am not sure why he declared them and didn't use them. I just copied the code and modified the mistake. He change them later if he wants to.